# How do I specify an ability for a route created by a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, ruby-on-rails-5.2, trestle-admin

I am using [Trestle Admin](https://github.com/TrestleAdmin/trestle), this is my route:

```
trestle_path        /admin         Trestle::Engine
```

When a user that is not an admin visits the `/admin` route, I would like CanCanCan to handle it like it handles all of the other unauthorized requests in my app.

The issue though is that I can't figure out how to specify that ability in my `ability.rb` or I can't figure out where to add an `authorize` statement to.

When I visit `/admin` in my app, this is what my log looks like:

```
Started GET "/admin" for ::1 at 2019-03-31 01:10:01 -0500
Processing by Trestle::DashboardController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/login
Filter chain halted as :require_authenticated_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So all that happens is that it redirects to `/admin/login` which is how the Trestle engine handles it.

But I would like for CanCanCan to hijack that and handle it like it handles all other unauthorized requests throughout my application via the rule in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, alert: exception.message }
    format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
  end
end
```

But, given that it isn't a Model or a controller I defined, I am not sure what to specify in my `ability.rb`.

I have tried the following, all to no avail:

```
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  else
    cannot :read, :trestle
  end
```

or:

```
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  else
    cannot :read, :admin
  end
```

Is it possible for me to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hack with route constraints:

```
class CanCanConstraint
  def initialize(action, resource)
    @resource, @action = resource, action
  end

  def matches?(request)
    # this will differ depending on your auth solution, for devise/warden:
    current_user = request.env['warden'].user        
    current_user && Ability.new(current_user).can?(@action, @resource) || false
  end
end

mount Trestle::Engine, at: '/admin', constraints: CanCanConstraint.new(:edit, :trestle)
match "/admin/*glob", to: "some_controller_when#trestle_not_authorized"
```

This way `/admin` only leads to trestle if user is authorized and has permission, otherwise first route will not match and you can handle request any way you like, for example with catch-all second route.

Depending on how you mount trestle - you may need to disable it's automount (`config.automount = false` in corresponding initializer)